# Требуются ли давать разрешения системным приложениям в Android

Tags: android, android-permissions

Интересно следующее, требуют ли предустановленные (`Calendar`, `Browser`, `Contacts` и т.д.) приложения (на устройствах с `OS Android`) в своих `Manifest`'ах разрешения на использование каких-либо ресурсов?

Или прописывать разрешения (`permission`) удел только сторонних приложений, в частности тех, что могут быть установлены через `Google Play`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ и да и нет.

**Да**, в том смысле, что декларировать в манифесте пермишены конечно надо,

**Нет** в том смысле, что на некоторые из пермишенов, некоторые приложения от рождения имеют правильные сертификаты, так что в рантайме не требуется подтверждения.

Правильный сертификат, это сертификат от вендора аппарата, которому безусловно доверяет ОС Android и не требует [специальных танцев с бубном](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 1):

Они являются практически такими же приложениями. Вот, к примеру, кусочек манифеста приложения `Settings`, найденного мной в исходниках:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_NETWORK_SCORES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HARDWARE_TEST" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MASTER_CLEAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIMAX_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIMAX_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.certinstaller.INSTALL_AS_USER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TETHER_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOVE_PACKAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BACKUP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USB" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_POINTER_SPEED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_KEYBOARD_LAYOUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.COPY_PROTECTED_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_PROFILE_AND_DEVICE_OWNERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONFIGURE_WIFI_DISPLAY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONFIGURE_DISPLAY_COLOR_MODE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SEARCH_INDEXABLES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.OEM_UNLOCK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USER_OEM_UNLOCK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.OVERRIDE_WIFI_CONFIG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USER_ACTIVITY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_APP_IDLE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PEERS_MAC_ADDRESS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_APP_OPS_RESTRICTIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.HIDE_NON_SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOWS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRINT_SERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK_SETTINGS" />
```

Много всего, не так ли? Брал [отсюда](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml).